Dealing with leaflet's lack of promises
I'm using the leaflet CDN script in a server-rendered app. The library's methods do not involve promises, so I often get weird UI glitches.
For example, when I use setView() it returns immediately; the only workaround is to set a timeout and hope for the best.
Is there a way to wait for that method to actually complete? (Maybe I didn't find that bit in the docs?) Or perhaps there's some trick I could use to overcome this problem?

There's lots of events in leafletjs. Do none of them fire?

^^ For instance, zoomend and moveend. If you wanted to wrap those with promises, here's how you'd do that.

Since Leaflet's Evented implements once(), it's possible to do it in a one-liner with await new Promise(res=>map.once('moveend', res));

I just did a quick-and-dirty test (I've never used Leaflet), and zoomend/moveend seem to fire after setView (I've never used Leaflet). Granted, they also fire at other times...

@T.J.Crowder Thanks I think that will solve my issue.

@IvanSanchez Thanks that seems to be what I'm looking for.

Only issue with listening for events (rather than awaiting a promise on the method that triggered them), is that map changes involve movement AND zooming, and the order is unpredictable.
